# Tablas de Hash Lista ligada en C

Tags: array, lista, hashmap, modular

Oigan, tengo una problema y no entiendo cómo resolverlo. La cosa es que debo hacer una tabla de hash y ordenar cierta cantidad de elementos. Pero bueno, todo es usando una lista ligada o doblemente ligada.

En resumen, se debe hacer un arreglo de listas (usando nodos obviamente) y el programa determina la posición del arreglo en que se insertará un elemento ingresado. Cada elemento se asigna dentro de una posición del arreglo y a la vez en la primera posición de la lista (cabe mencionar que al inicio todas las listas están vacías) Ésto lo realiza usando aritmética modular de manera que el numero ingresado modulo el tamaño te da la posición del arreglo.

El tamaño del arreglo tiene que ser un numero primo constante, pero no importa demasiado, he decidido usar el 23. Si dos elementos coinciden en una misma posición del arreglo, el elemento se agrega siguiente en la lista, en esa misma posición de arreglo. La cosa es que no tengo idea de como inicializar el arreglo con las listas. Se debe hacer un arreglo de elementos de tipo nodo *apuntador o cómo?? Deben inicializarse a NULL supongo, pero no tengo idea de cómo realizarlo dentro del arreglo

Pueden ayudarme?? Gracias!!

Disculpen, alguien tiene idea de cómo hacer un arreglo (array) de listas ligadas, necesito ayuda sobre cómo se hacen y cómo realizar operaciones dentro de cada casilla del arreglo.

**Edit**. La lista ligada puede ser simple o doble, usando nodos obviamente, la idea es que dentro de cada posición o casilla del arreglo (array) exita una lista y poder agregar elementos a listas en una posición específica del arreglo

Ejemplo

|..Posición..||

|------|a|-----||..contiene lista ligada 1..|

|------|b|-----||..contiene lista ligada 2..|

...

Quiero guardar el numero 21 en la lista 1 que se encuentra dentro de la posición 'a' del array

Entonces quiero ver si me pueden dar un consejo sobre cómo hacer el array y cómo acceder a cada una de las listas en cada posición

Anexo código de lo que llevo, pero no le presten mucha atención porque ni siquiera se acerca a funcionar

```
//m=Cantidad de elementos del array, k es valor a guardar
void inicializar(){
    nodo* aux = (nodo*) malloc(sizeof(nodo));
    for(int i=0;i<m;i++){
        aux=NULL;
        primero=aux;
        primero->siguiente=NULL;
        primero->atras=NULL;
        ultimo=primero;
    }
}

void insertarClave(int k){
    int pos, i;
    nodo* nuevo = (nodo*) malloc(sizeof(nodo));
    (nuevo->clave)=k;
    pos=k&m;

    T[pos]=nuevo;
    primero=nuevo;
    ultimo=nuevo;
    primero->siguiente=NULL;
    primero->atras=NULL;

    for(i=0;i<m;i++)
        printf(" %d", nuevo->clave);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya lo tengo, basicamente al ser un array de nodos, cada casilla del array es el inicio de una lista. En lugar de usar un nodo "primero" o "cabeza", se usa Lista[j] para cada inicio de lista en cada una de las posiciones del array